# Class casting to a type

Tags: c++, types, casting

Anybody know how to implement a casting rule in C++ for one class?

Let's say I have a class Mark that has a double-type member. And I want this class to be cast-able to double:

```
Mark m(9);
double d = (double)m;
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You should avoid casts, so you should probably avoid finding a solution to this "problem". Just add a member to your class that returns the value: it's easier to read and not implicit. For example, I have no idea reading this what the value of `d` should be. 9 maybe? Or is 9 just some other value, like a grid size, and this cast returns the average value? Make it a member that's callable like `m.average_grid_value()`, and nobody has to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have `operator double()` inside your class. For example

```
class Mark
{
     //...
public:
     operator double()
     {
         return the_member;
     }
 };
```

Comment: I think you need to drop the first `double`

Comment: `operator double()` suffice? You don't need to specify the return type.Might as well mention that this is a [conversion operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr385.htm).

Comment: But note that this makes the type implicitly convertible to double, not even requiring a cast, behaviour that is not neccessarily bad in itself but that one needs to be aware of. Only C++11 allows marking conversion operators `explicit`.